# What do the different item orb colors in NieR Replicant 1.2247 mean?

Tags: nier-replicant-1.22474487139

The collectable item orbs in *NieR Replicant 1.2247* come in different colors. I've seen yellow, green, and white. What do the different item orb colors mean?

[image: item orbs]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The various colors indicated either the purpose or rarity of the items:

- **Green**<sup>1</sup> - items that are green are Common or Uncommon drops from enemies
- **Yellow/Gold**<sup>1</sup> - items that are yellow/gold are Rare drops from enemies
- **White** - items that are white are typically over-world items that will spawn. These can range from raw materials, consumables, or key items

---

<sup>1</sup> [Source](https://www.rpgsite.net/feature/11032-nier-replicant-upgrade-materials-where-to-get-all-items-for-weapon-upgrades)